# Make Spring Boot application discoverable with zeroconf

Tags: java, windows, spring-boot, zeroconf, jmdns

How can I make a `Java` web app application built with `Spring Boot` discoverable with `zeroconf`?

I tried the following with `JmDNS` but it does not seem to work:

```
@Bean
public JmDNS jmdns() {
    try {
        JmDNS jmdns = JmDNS.create(InetAddress.getLocalHost());
        ServiceInfo serviceInfo = ServiceInfo.create("_http._tcp.local.", "appName", port, "path=index.html");
        jmdns.registerService(serviceInfo);
        return jmdns;
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

After this I expected to be able to see the service in the Windows 10 network overview, but it does not appear there.

**Edit**

The application is listed in the avahi browser, which shows it somehow works.

But my goal is to have it visible in the Windows network service overview.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: I just wonder if maybe InetAddress.getLocalHost() is the problem? I should try with the non-localhost address. Unfortunately I have no way to test with that project now.